# How to create multiple components of a service with c'tor dependencies

Tags: constructor, dependencies, castle-windsor

I'd like to create several similar services which can be destinguished and accessed by their names (=keys).

For the service implementation I want to use classes with c'tor dependencies like this:

```
public interface IXYService
{
 string Tag { get; set; }
}

public class _1stXYService : IXYService
{
 public _1stXYService(string Tag)
    {
        this.Tag = Tag;
    }

    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

What I tried was to use 'AddComponentWithProperties' to have a concrete instance created which is accessible via a given key:

```
...
    IDictionary l_xyServiceInitParameters = new Hashtable { { "Tag", "1" } };
    l_container.AddComponentWithProperties
        (
            "1st XY service", 
            typeof(IXYService), 
            typeof(_1stXYService), 
            l_xyServiceInitParameters
        );

    l_xyServiceInitParameters["Tag"] = "2";
    l_container.AddComponentWithProperties
        (
            "2nd XY service", 
            typeof(IXYService), 
            typeof(_1stXYService), 
            l_xyServiceInitParameters
        );
...

var service = l_container[serviceName] as IXYService;
```

However, the dependencies were not resolved and hence the services are not available.

Using IWindsorContainer.Resolve(...) to populate the parameters is not desired.

Construction by XML works, but is not in all cases sufficient.

How could I achieve my goals?

Comment: so you want to resolve the service by its Tag property?

Comment: All windsor components have an ID, which is a string. Would that be enough? Or does it have to be your own Tag property?

Comment: The ID, in case of using 'AddComponentWithProperties' it's the 'key' parameter, would fully fit. In the example these are the keys "1st XY service" and "2nd XY service".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to define the Tag property at registration-time:

```
[Test]
public void Named() {
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<IXYService>()
        .ImplementedBy<_1stXYService>()
        .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("Tag").Eq("1"))
        .Named("1st XY Service"));
    container.Register(Component.For<IXYService>()
        .ImplementedBy<_1stXYService>()
        .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("Tag").Eq("2"))
        .Named("2nd XY Service"));

    Assert.AreEqual("2", container.Resolve<IXYService>("2nd XY Service").Tag);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mauricio, this way it works like intended!
I guess I should put a book on "Windsor Castle" on my wish list for x-mas to find out about the many ways to push and pull objects into and from the container.

Comment: hey, it's being considered ;-) http://castle.uservoice.com/pages/16605-official-castle-project-feedback-forum/suggestions/327076-we-should-write-a-using-castle-book?ref=title